# how to remove serial numbers from dictionary for further operations?

Tags: python, arrays, dictionary, for-loop, matrix

I just converted a dictionary into an array... something like this

```
dict_t = {1: 0.1, 2: 0.2, 3: 0.3, 4: 0.4 }
```

this is what I obtained:-

```
w =      [[ 1.  0.1  ]
          [ 2.  0.2  ]
          [ 3.  0.3  ]
          [ 4.  0.4  ]
```

this is what I desired:-

**question 1 - how to get the below-desired result ?**

```
w      = [[ 0.1  ]
          [ 0.2  ]
          [ 0.3  ]
          [ 0.4  ]]
```

further, I was indexing these values into a matrix format.

**question-2 how to index the value of w ?**

for each value of w, I want this (F matrix) local  matrix,

F = np.array([0],[w*l/2],[-w*l*l/12],[0],[w*l/2],[w*l*l/12])

further, all these F matrices should be added in a particular fashion to get the global matrix (shown below in the desired operation)
after all the operation delta_F will give a column matrix .

```
dof = 15
delta_F = np.zeros(15)

for i in range(w):
        F = np.array([0],[w*l/2],[-w*l*l/12],[0],[w*l/2],[w*l*l/12])
        rows, cols = dof,1
        F_temp = [([0]*cols) for i in range(rows)]
        F_temp[3i:3i+6,0] = F
        delta_F += F_temp
        print(delta_F)
```

***desired operation***:-

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hd79R.jpg)

Comment: Question 1 answer: `[[i] for i in dict_t.values()]`

Comment: @BiRD , can I do this step without changing it into a list?

Comment: Do you mean a list of list ? Can you update your answer to show what you desire

Answer (score 0):

Question 1, this should give the output you want:

```
dict_t = {1: 0.1, 2: 0.2, 3: 0.3, 4: 0.4 }
output = [[v for v in dict_t.values()]]
print(output) #[[0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4]]
```